# Compute probability

Tags: self-study, density-function, joint-distribution

Suppose that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are $\text{i.i.d.} \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$. Let $t > 0$ be a ﬁxed constant.

(i) Compute $P(X/Y \leq t)$
(ii) Compute $ P(XY \leq t)$
(iii) Compute $ P(XY/Z \leq t)$

I found the solution for (i) part undermining the different values of $t$.
$ P(X/Y \leq t) = \int_0^1\int_0^{yt}dx dy  = t/2 $ ; when $t\leq 1$

I am finding hard time to lake limits for different values of $t$ i.e when $t\leq 1 $ and $t>1$

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework problem, and if it is so, please add the `homework` or `self-study` tag as appropriate. With regard to parts (i) and (ii), first draw a diagram of the $x$-$y$ plane, indicate on it the region where $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is nonzero as well as the regions where $X/Y \leq t$ etc.  You will have different diagrams depending on the numerical value of $t$.  Integrate the joint pdf over the regions to get the answers you need.

Comment: @Glen_b I have noticed some people (here as well as on math.SE) positively bristling at the  suggestion that the `homework` tag be added. "It is _not_ homework," they insist, "I am studying this stuff on my own." These people are much happier tagging the problem as `self-study`. My responses and/or answer treat both tags the same....

Comment: Notice that the event $X/Y\le t$ can be written both as $X\le tY$ and $Y\ge (\frac{1}{t})X.$ The chance of the latter is $1$ minus the chance of $Y\lt (\frac{1}{t})X.$ Because the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is identical to that of $(Y,X)$, this latter chance is the same as that of $X\lt(\frac{1}{t})Y$ which (because the distributions are continuous) is that of $X\le(\frac{1}{t})Y.$ When $t\gt 1,$ $\frac{1}{t}\lt 1,$ which reduces the calculation to the one you have already successfully performed.

Comment: @whuber I understood your explanation, the only part I am struggling with is why are we using the fact that $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ have same distribution.

Comment: Because it's simpler than doing the same calculation twice!